# Return view and send data to react after passport.js oauth

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, passport.js

First let me say that sorry if this is a simple question, I'm new to react and express and couldn't find the answer on SO.

I'm trying to pass data to a react object as well as render a view based off of a passport.js return route.

I have the object i need to pass I just can't figure out how to pass it.

First the user hits the auth route

```
router.get('/steam',
    passport.authenticate('steam'),
    (req, res) => {
    //Not used
});
```

Then after they login through steam they're returned to this route:

```
router.get('/steam/return',
    passport.authenticate('steam', { failureRedirect: '/' }),
    (req, res) => {
        res.redirect('/dashboard');
});
```

From here I'm passing them to the /dashboard route where im taking the user object and creating another call to grab their library and then sending the data to the view:

```
router.get('/', (req, res, next) => {
    var OwnedGamesReqUri = 'http://api.steampowered.com/IPlayerService/GetOwnedGames/v0001/?key=' + process.env.STEAM_API + '&steamid=' + req.user.steamid + '&format=json&include_appinfo=1';
    request(OwnedGamesReqUri, (error, response, body) => {
      if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
        var resObj = JSON.parse(body);
        //name, playtime_forever, playtime_2weeks, img_icon_url, img_logo_url
        res.render('dashboard', { user: req.user, games: resObj.response.games});
      }
    });
});
```

I'm able to grab all of the data I need in the dashboard view via handlebars but the problem I'm facing is what I can do to pass the ownedgames data to a react object in another JS file. I have a react component set up in another file that is loaded to the dashboard via a bundle file. I'm assuming this needs to go to the server but I'm just not exactly sure how to achieve this.

Comment: Generally speaking, you could either make ajax calls to pull that data in, save the data to a global javascript variable when you render the page on the server and pick that variable up in your react component, or you can render your react server side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question isn't about reactjs or passportjs. It's basically how we can pass a variable in server-side javascript to client-side javascript. So you can use that variable in whatever the framework you use in the client-side.

The simplest way to achieve this is rendering your value as variable declaration within an inline script tag in your template. So your client js will have a global variable with that value, which can access from anywhere in your client side scripts.

As an example, if have a variable with string value as follows

```
var test = 'abc';
```

You can render it in your template as a variable declaration within a script tag.

```
res.render('template', test)
```

template file:

```
<script>
    var test = '{{test}}';
</script>
```

Now this template will generate an HTML page as follows.

```
<script>
    var test = 'abc';
</script>
```

So `test` variable will be a global client side javascript variable with value `'abc'`, which can access from any other javascript code on the same page.

Even though this is simple as above for a string variable, things get complicated when you are trying to send an object. Because object variables render in the template as `[Object object]`. To avoid this, you need to send stringify version of your object before sending it the handlebar template.

```
var data = JSON.stringify({ user: req.user, games: resObj.response.games});
res.render('dashboard', data);
```

Then your `dashboard` template needs to have script tag with the variable declaration in addition to its original content.

```
//...
<script>
    var data = {{data}};
</script>
//...
```

Now, `data` will be a global variable in your client side and you can use it in your reactjs code to access `user` and `games`.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to do this, depending on how your React component manages its state.

1. Reactive state (RxJS, mobx, nx-observe):
   The easiest to deal with, your component as well as the non-js code can both access these stores and catch up on the updates together. This provides a very loose coupling between the data provider and consumer.
2. Component with a flux pattern:
   If your component is using Redux, Reflux or any other flux based library to manage state, you can export corresponding actions/functions from your flux code which any JavaScript code can call to update your component's state.
3. State maintained within the component:
   Somewhat messy. In this case your component can export a callback which your script can call to send it new data.

Comment: This doesn't answer how 1, 2, or 3 receives the data from server after server-side authentication